# What is the limitation on size of list attribute in Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, limits, lightning-datatable

We have created a lightning component where we are displaying transaction records. We have used lightning datatable and also implemented pagination. Data that is to be displayed is retrieved by API callout, we are not storing anything on salesforce org. There is possibility that millions of records retrieved. How many maximum records can browser or lightning component can handle in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is a attribute level size defined but there is a size limitation for the entire lightning component payload which is 4 MB

> Client Payload Data Limit Increased to 4 MB The framework batches
> server-side actions in the queue into one server request. The request
> payload includes all of the actions and their data serialized into
> JSON. The request payload limit has been increased to 4 MB.
>
> Previously, it was 1 MB. Use action.setParams() in JavaScript to set
> data for an action to be passed to a server-side controller.

Read [winter 2018 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_lc_client_data_limit.htm)